# Ant : adding multiple jars in classpath dynamically

Tags: ant, classpath

How to dynamically add jars to javac classpath in ant ?

e.g.

the properties file should be (this list can change and include different jars in different directories): 
dyna.jars=../../dir1/api1.jar;../dir2/api2.jar

in build.xml

```
            <javac
                srcdir="${javac.srcdir}"
                .....
            >
            <classpath refid="${dyna.jars}" />

            </javac>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I can't quite tell if `dir1` and `dir2` are going to be changing also or just the JARs in those directories but assuming those directories are going to be named the same, the following will include all JARs under `dir` and `dir2` and create a `<path>` with `id="dyna.jars"`. Note that it should be `refid="dyna.jars"` and not `refid="${dyna.jars}"`

```
<path id="dyna.jars">
    <fileset dir="../../dir1">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="../../dir2">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<javac srcdir="${javac.srcdir}" .....>
    <classpath refid="dyna.jars" />
</javac>
```